# Yii2 3 таблицы и 2 ActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord, relation

Доброго времени суток.

Есть 3 таблицы и 2 сущности, одна из таблиц содержит общие свойства, другие 2 содержат подробности каждой сущности.

Вопрос как инстанцировать конкретный класс сущности не стоит, тут можно использовать шаблон single table, а вот как инстанцировать конкретный класс с подробностями без дополнительной связи.

"Теперь перефразирую вопрос правильно как написать свой велосипед с квадратными колёсами"

Жду советов по сабжу, про связь в конкретном классе с классом конкретных подробностей писать не надо сам знаю как это сделать и если ничего интересного не будет, буду реализовывать так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!
Попробуйте ExtendedBehavior из этого пакета:
https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-ar-behaviors

Да, Вам все равно придется определить связь, но лично пользоваться ей не обязательно - поведение обеспечит прозрачный доступ к полям родительской сущности.